# valid json becomes invalid json when calling a javascript function

Tags: karate

```
* def xyz = 'abc'
* def abc = {"pratyush" : '#(xyz)'}
* def editJson =
"""
function(s)
{
var x = s.x
karate.log(x)
}
"""
* def p = call editJson ({"x" :abc})
```

actual output -{pratyush=abc} 
expected output  - {"pratyush":'abc'}

Answer (score 1):

use pretty to print it like `JSON`

```
karate.log(karate.pretty(x))
```

other than that it doesn't make it as invalid JSON

```
* def editJson =
"""
function(s)
{
var x = s.x
return x;
}
"""
* def p = call editJson ({"x" :abc})
* print p
# {"pratyush":'abc'}
```